# How to make the left sidebar fixed while scrolling down the page

Tags: html

I have a left sidebar and a main menu.....i need to keep the left sidebar fixed while scrolling down the page....but am not getting it.
This is my code.
Can anyone help me how to do it?

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
           <!-- START Left navbar-->
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

              <li>
                 <!-- Button used to collapse the left sidebar. Only visible on tablet and desktops-->
                 <a href="" data-toggle-state="aside-collapsed" class="hidden-xs">
                    <em class="fa fa-navicon"></em>
                 </a>
                 <!-- Button to show/hide the sidebar on mobile. Visible on mobile only.-->
                 <a href="" data-toggle-state="aside-toggled" data-no-persist="true" class="visible-xs sidebar-toggle">
                    <em class="fa fa-navicon"></em>
                 </a>
              </li>
           </ul>
           <!-- END Left navbar-->
           <!-- START Right Navbar-->
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <!-- <li>
                 <a href="" data-search-open="">
                    <em class="icon-magnifier"></em>
                 </a>
              </li> -->
              <!-- Fullscreen (only desktops)-->
              <!-- <li class="visible-lg">
                 <a href="" data-toggle-fullscreen="">
                    <em class="fa fa-expand"></em>
                 </a>
              </li> -->
              <li  class="dropdown user">
                <!-- <span style="color: #ddd;"></span> -->
                 <a title="Log Out" style="text-decoration: none; box-shadow:0px 0px 0px; cursor: pointer;" class="dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown"
                data-close-others="true">
                    {{loggedInUser.userFirstName}} {{loggedInUser.userLastName}} &nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>

                 </a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="" ng-click="logOut()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed;overflow:auto;` on the left one. You may need to adjust the position of the right one. Use `position:relative;` on the right panel.

Comment: Try to do this by yourself :)